# Rails - Has Many Through - New, Save and Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems with has_many through relationship in Rails. I checked the Rails Guides but they have a poor documentation for has_many through's effects in controllers in views.

**Here are my Models:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships
  has_many :twitter_accounts, through: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships
  has_many :projects, through: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :twitter_account
end
```

**And the routes file =>**

```
resources :projects do
  resources :twitter_accounts
end
```

**Now I'm able to test the relationship from the console without any error:**

```
Project.first.twitter_accounts
Project.first.twitter_memberships
TwitterAccount.first.twitter_memberships
TwitterAccount.first.projects
```

**Also I can create records too, which works perfectly fine:**

```
Project.first.twitter_accounts.create(name: "bar")
```

**Creates the correct twitter_account and twitter_membership data:**

```
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_accounts" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test_record"], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00]]

SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_memberships" ("created_at", "project_id", "twitter_account_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00], ["project_id", 1], ["twitter_account_id", 8], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00]]
```

So far, all the code and console operations are working fine. I created both TwitterAccount and TwitterMembership successfully with the command above. But I'm stucked with the controllers and views. In this URL:

http://foobar.com/projects/my-first-project/twitter_accounts/new

I have this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @twitter_account], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  <%= f.text_field :account_id, :class => 'text_field' %>
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**and app/controllers/twitter_accounts_controller.rb file =>**

```
class TwitterAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_twitter_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new
  end

  def create
    @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new(twitter_account_params)
    @twitter_account.save
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_twitter_account
      @twitter_account = TwitterAccount.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def twitter_account_params
      params.require(:twitter_account).permit(:name, :account_id)
    end
end
```

When I submit this form, it's only creating "TwitterAccount" and not creating the "TwitterMembership". I couldn't understand why it's only creating "TwitterAccount" and not creating "TwitterMembership" too.

As I explained before, I was able to create both of them with a single command in Rails console:

```
Project.first.twitter_accounts.create(name: "bar")
```

Can you please explain my the details for creating and editing objects in has_many through relation and answer my question below.

Thanks in advance.